# Join multiple objects into 1 object without combining the vertices?

Tags: objects, vertices, faces

is there a way to combine multiple objects without actually attaching them to each other?

I tried parenting them to a empty axis but I can't switch modes from the parent.
I would have to go through and select each child object to do it. :<[image]

Comment: Could you clarify, what the problem with the current "Join" is. (Ctrl J)

Comment: I need to have the objects be seperate so they don't warp during rigging. I am using low poly models so combining them makes it look awful. I just want to be able to treat them as 1 object when in object mode.

Comment: could you please make a screenshot of your group of objects?

Comment: here we go this is what my blender hierarchy looks like. I am trying to rig a 64 model for unity but 64 models aren't one big mesh.

Answer (score 1):

Try using lattice modifier.

To get the modifier to all objects select them with box selection and after this click in any of them, add the lattice modifier and press ctrl-l>modifiers to give all of them the lattice modifier.

here's an example of this:[image: ex1]

Comment: let me elaborate a bit more. I am making a n64 character from smash bros. I need to some how parent all the pieces to something that will allow me to select them as a whole and go into different modes.

Comment: are you sure that what you want isn't join? i mean, i think there is no way to make exatly what you want, or you parent all the items and edit them individually after or you just join them.  you said "I need to have the objects be seperate so they don't ** warp **during rigging." can you give examples? because maybe the problem can easly be fixed with weight correction

Comment: I don't think 64 models never actually connected the joints which is what I am trying to rig for unity3d. I don't want it to be one single mesh because I want the parts to move separately with the bones. I also wanted to somehow parent or join them following these rules so that its just 1 mesh or object with multiple parts.  I really am new to this 3d modeling thing and i'm not really sure what I need to do to accomplish this.

Comment: you can join them without "connecting" them, just link each part to a single bone before joining the parts